# how linux kernel is implemented?

Tags: linux, multithreading, kernel, mapping

I need to know, how Linux kernel is implemented? I want to understand which modules are implemented Multi Thread, which ones are implemented single thread and also when running a multi thread application, how does the user thread to kernel mapping thread is done? (is it m to n or m to 1 or does it have 1 to n?).
if there is a manual or paper or even a white paper about, it would be a great help for me if introduced. (i was unable finding sources about my question, especially my first question)

Can anyone give me a clue?
Thanks.

Comment: The linux kernel covers 15 million lines of code, it implements a number of different threading/concurrency primitives,  and uses them extensively in most of its different sub-systems and drivers, as well as providing APIs which concurrency libraries are built on top of. Could you be a bit more specific about what you actually want?

Comment: thanks a lot Sisyphus. sorry if made confuse. i want such a statistical report about what i mentioned (not exact information on every driver or ...), i mean, while implementing each module, the developer didn't speak about his method of coding for that module? for example, is there a statistic which point to drivers (in general) and tell what percent of them are implemented concurrent? (am i clear now)

Comment: Hey guys, Really there is not any answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a one-stop shop for your question. Your best option here is to read ALL the kernel documentation. There's not much else you can do - concurrency is just fundamental to the kernel, almost every part of the kernel needs to be aware that it may be running at the same time as other parts. In that vein, the simple answer is that *all* of the kernel is implemented as multi-threaded - although highly-concurrent would probably be a better term because the concept of a 'thread' is also *implemented* by the kernel and kernel concurrency is not necessarily thread-based. Every individual driver needs to be aware that parts of it can be executing concurrently, so they *all* have to use the internal synchronisation techniques to ensure the safety of shared data.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/

You'll also find subsystem specific stuff on various websites and in various books, although they'll also be variously out of date...

- http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0131453483/downloads/gorman_book.pdf
- http://www.amazon.co.uk/Linux-Kernel-Development-Developers-Library/dp/0672329468/
- http://www.amazon.co.uk/Understanding-Linux-Kernel-Daniel-Bovet-ebook/dp/B0043D2E54
- https://lwn.net/Articles
- http://whatisthekernel.blogspot.co.uk/
- http://linuxburps.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/linux-kernel-synchronization-primitives.html
- http://www.linux-mag.com/id/2195/
- http://www.linux-mag.com/id/2316/